# customer UISearchDisplayControllerdimmingview

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I click uisearchbar,it shows above,an opacity black view shows?
this is the [image: image link]
How can I customer the view?

Answer (score 0):

```
UIView *yourCustomView = [[UIView alloc] init];//don't forget its frame
yourCustomView.tag = 99;
UIView *supV = self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.superview;
UIView *supsupV = supV.superview;

for (UIView *view in supsupV.subviews) {
    for (UIView *sencondView in view.subviews) {
        if ([sencondView isKindOfClass:[NSClassFromString(@"_UISearchDisplayControllerDimmingView") class]])
        {
            NSLog(@"_UISearchDisplayControllerDimmingView");
            if (![sencondView viewWithTag:99]) {
                [sencondView addSubview:yourCustomView];
            }
            sencondView.alpha = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this might solve OP's question, please add an explanation. Why should OP use this code?